# How can I add an Apple email address to an email client such as Evolution?

Tags: icloud, unix

I somehow ended up with an Apple email address.

How can I use my '@me.com' email in my email client (Evolution in Debian)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you actually want to use this email account? It sounds like you got it unwantedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the IMAP settings to use for your mail client at this [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864).

**Incoming mail server**

```
Server name: imap.mail.me.com
SSL Required: Yes
Port: 993
Username: example@me.com (use your @me.com address from your iCloud account)
Password: Your iCloud password
```

**Outgoing mail server**

```
Server name: smtp.mail.me.com
SSL Required: Yes
Port: 587
SMTP Authentication Required: Yes
Username: example@me.com (use your @me.com address from your iCloud account)
Password: Your iCloud password
```

Comment: +1 solved my problem although the support url is broken.

Comment: Works for me, though theres a long lasting bug with Apple's support site. Trying again usually suffices.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I read the support article before searching here. I just keep getting a failed to authenticate error... (I have confirmed that my password is correct). Thoughts?